# run a javascript function for specific css .class selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JavaScript library and it uses this function for example to convert English numbers to Persian:

```
persianJs("345").englishNumber().toString(); //returns: ۳۴۵
```

I have an html structure to show some dynamic numerical values like this:

```
<span class="price"><!-- price amount  --></span>
```

How can I run the JavaScript function in header or footer to display any ***price amount*** in Persian format?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, what you're looking for is the method `querySelector` 
`document.querySelector('.price').innerHTML = persianJs("345").englishNumber().toString();`

Comment: Please post some part of code, what have you tried.

Comment: Thank you! If I use `persianJs().englishNumber().toString();` does it recognize **.price** selector content and start converting it?

Comment: @Jon That is exactly my problem. I am looking for a JavaScript code that detects **.price** selectors and then do the conversion function for those selectors _content, but honestly I don't know how it is doable.

Comment: You can put any value in _span_ using this `document.getElementsByClassName("price")[0].innerHTML='abc';`

Comment: @Jon I have a dynamic page which is producing some numbers, so the numbers are generated and I just need convert these generated numbers through above javascript function. That is why I am looking for a way to find these numbers via their selectors and then convert them through Javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will convert all the .price span to english numbers on your code base.

```
    window.onload = function(){
      var els = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
      els.forEach(function(item) {
        item.textContent = persianJs(item.textContent).englishNumber().toString();
      });
    }
```

Comment: If you feel this answer worked for you, please make this as accepted answer, it will help the community.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  document.getElementsByClassName("price")[0].innerText

```js
//var pNumber =persianJs("345").englishNumber().toString(); //returns: ۳۴۵
var pNumber="۳۴۵";
document.getElementsByClassName("price")[0].innerText=pNumber;
```

```html
<span class="price"><!-- price amount  --></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I'm on the same page with you, but I think you need to specify the function that will be triggered each time when you need, and this function should query all places where you need to change the price amount.

For instance:

```
function updatePrice() {
   return persianJs("345").englishNumber().toString();
};

window.onload = function(){
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
      if(elements && elements.length) {
         elements.forEach(el => el.textContent = updatePrice())
      } 
}
```

It's just my vision of your problem, but again I'm not sure that I correctly understand you...

Comment: Thanks @yuriy-petrichenko ; Yes I want to change the price format anywhere which there is **.price** selector. It seems your suggestion is doing it but the **345** is just a sample number, in fact I have a _dynamic_  _value_ instead of **345** and I need that _value_ be processed and converted through JS function. Does your suggestion convert any value of .price selector element by using JavaScript function?